# Ionic 2 installation issues

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, npm-install

I am trying to use Ionic 2 on Windows 7 x64 bit and got stuck when using ionic start command. I have tried to read tutorials and installation instructions but got no luck. Here's the details of my problem:

1. Found depreciation warnings during cordova and ionic installation:

https://postimg.org/image/vf3qn8z9b/

2. Then it shows errors using following command in ionic:

   ionic start newProject sidemenu --v2

https://postimg.org/image/4vz80prq5/

context of my npm-debug.log:

```
 9284 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    69285 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
    69286 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
    69286 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
    69286 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
    69286 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: ia32
    69287 verbose stack Error: node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    69287 verbose stack Exit status 1
    69287 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
    69287 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    69287 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    69287 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
    69287 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    69287 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    69287 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
    69287 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    69288 verbose pkgid node-sass@3.10.1
    69289 verbose cwd C:\Users\Lime\newIonicProj
    69290 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    69291 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    69292 error node v7.3.0
    69293 error npm  v3.10.10
    69294 error code ELIFECYCLE
    69295 error node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    69295 error Exit status 1
    69296 error Failed at the node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
    69296 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    69296 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
    69296 error not with npm itself.
    69296 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    69296 error     node scripts/build.js
    69296 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    69296 error     npm bugs node-sass
    69296 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    69296 error     npm owner ls node-sass
    69296 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    69297 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**Applied Solutions:**

1. Installed nodejs 7.3.0 (current version as of now).

Note: I have tried to install x64 bit but since I got errors, so I switched to x86 version and still no luck. I have also tried to downgrade nodejs to 6.9.2 and v4.4.7 but have made no progress at all.

2. Upgraded npm using "npm install -g npm", clear cache and update registry
3. Tried to rebuild node-sass
4. Tried to install minimatch, uuid and fsevents manually

Any idea, what I missed during the installation? I got same problems when creating projects using ionic version 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After series of uninstalling and installing the all dependencies, I found out that the problem occurred because of the incompatibility of node-sass to the current version of nodejs. I have solved the problem by:

1. installing x86 nodejs version 7.3.0
2. install cordova and ionic (not beta)
3. updated node-sass "install -g node-sass"
4. built node-sass again by using the command "npm rebuild node-sass"

After that, the when I tried to run "ionic serve" command, an error occurred. The error message was:

> "Ionic serve error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/.../IonicTest/www/index.html'"

5. run the command "npm run build" [reference:](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1420)

And cheers! It's already working :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, node 7 requires node.sass v13.12.0 or higher

69288 verbose pkgid node-sass@3.10.1
 69289 verbose cwd C:\Users\Lime\newIonicProj
 69290 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 69291 error argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
 69292 error node v7.3.0

Check supported versions here : https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases?after=3.4.0-RC1