# Getting an error while installing ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to install ionic2, I've already installed node.js (v6.10) and android sdk.

When I run

> npm install -g ionic cordova

I get this error:

> npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of mime-types with
>   mime-types@2.0.14 npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of
>   cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2 npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing
>   bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0 npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1
>   replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0 npm WARN
>   In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of request with
>   request@2.51.0 npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of
>   ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.0 npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0 npm ERR!
>   argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
>   "cordova" npm ERR! node v6.10.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920 npm ERR! code
>   ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall rename
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920' ->
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920' ->
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm
>   ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
>   ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/ege/Desktop/ionic2/npm-debug.log

Comment: What operating system are you installling to? If on Mac or Ubuntu you must use sudo before npm install -g cordova ionic. Its possiby a permissions error

Comment: @yaboiduke it's Mac sudo didn't solve my issue, I'm gonna uninstall node and re-install with homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-installing node via homebrew fixed the issue:

```
npm cache clean 
brew uninstall --force node
rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew install node
```

edit: another solution (for Windows): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41414117/6683139

Answer (score 0):

For everyone getting this kind of errors on Mac and Linux, please install the NodeJS through NVM
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

It's not a good idea to sudo npm